# Using 'GOTO' to skip specific portion of a script in TSQL

Tags: t-sql

I have a problem I am struggling to wrap my head around. My goal is to update specific columns based on a strict where clause. The issue is that I have 2 database, which are very similar, however, one is an older version and the other a newer version, so one contains a specific column and the other does not. I thought of using GOTO to specify which portion of the script should be run, depending on a 'version' result.

Example:

```
DECLARE @version INT;
SET @version =
(
    SELECT TOP 1 CAST(Version AS INT)
FROM VersionTable
ORDER BY ID DESC

);

IF @version <= 1
    GOTO Version_A;

IF @version > 1
    GOTO Version_B;

Version_A:

UPDATE table
SET Column1 = 'A'
    Column2 = 'B'
WHERE Id = '123456'

Version_B:

UPDATE table
SET Column1 = 'A'
    Column2 = 'B'
    Column3 = 'C'
WHERE Id = '123456'
```

This works perfectly for Version_B. Unfortunately, if @version <= 1 the correct path is chosen, but the query fails due to invalid column 'Column3'

Perhaps there is a better way of achieving this, but this is the best I could think of. Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Sascha.

Comment: `Column3 = (CASE WHEN @version > 1 THEN 'C'  ELSE Column3 END)` is this works for you?

Comment: Hi Arulkumar, thank you for taking a look at this. It is not so much an issue with updating column3 but an issue with not being able to run the script if the version is <=1 because column3 does not exist in that database. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Dynamic SQL would help you here

Comment: Beware of using [`GOTO`](https://www.xkcd.com/292/), only use as a last resort (and look around you for lurking raptors first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Btw: Your code is missing some commas...

I doubt, that the approach is the best, but you do not tell us, what you are really trying to achieve. Better than a `GOTO` might be a *code-block* for the `IF` like here

Btw2: Your code looks, as if an `IF @version <=1 blah1 ELSE blah2` would suffice. But - as you used independant IFs - I'll stick to your pattern.

```
IF @version <= 1
BEGIN
    UPDATE SomeTable
    SET Column1 = 'A',
        Column2 = 'B'
    WHERE Id = '123456'
END

IF @version > 1
BEGIN
    UPDATE SomeTable
    SET Column1 = 'A',
        Column2 = 'B',
        Column3 = 'C'
    WHERE Id = '123456'
END
```

Another option was *dynamic SQL*, something along this:

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
IF @version <= 1
SET @cmd='UPDATE SomeTable
          SET Column1 = ''A'',
              Column2 = ''B''
           WHERE Id = ''123456'';'

IF @version > 1
SET @cmd='UPDATE SomeTable
    SET Column1 = ''A'',
        Column2 = ''B'',
        Column3 = ''C''
    WHERE Id = ''123456'';'

EXEC(@cmd);
```

Comment: Indeed it would, and maybe a tad better with an `ELSE IF @version > 1` and better still, just `ELSE`?

Comment: @Shnugo, thank you, I changed it into dynamic SQL which worked perfectly.